# Min number of characters removed from X in order to obtain X as substring that does not contain Y

Tags: java, string, numbers, substring, string-matching

Came around an interesting question from spox. Please share your views on this problem.

**Input**

Input contains some test cases. Each test cases contains two lines, First is X and second is Y. Length of X <= 10000, Length of Y <= 1000.

**Output**

For each test cases, You should output exactly one integer is the minimum number of characters to be remove

***Example***

**Input:**

ababaa

aba

**Output:**
1

Comment: no homeworks please!!

Comment: Show us what have you tried

Comment: @Vignesh Paramasivam  It doesn't look like homework. Task not so simple.

Comment: Then please tell me where you're stuck with while trying this. How can you say it is difficult without trying?

Comment: @Vignesh Paramasivam I posted my answer, but I can't find proof that it correct.

Comment: Mainly having problem with the algorithm. If you can tell one algorithm that would be of great help. 


[link](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PSTRING/)

Answer (score 0):

Let define *overlaping_cout(x)* as number of occurencies contains character on position x.

Finde x such as *overlaping_cout(x)* is maximum. then remove x. repeat previous step until *overlaping_cout(x)*==0 for all x.